# SalesForce chat widget breaks JQuery Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, chat

we face some issues with events of ajax form after opening SalesForce chat. We use JQuery and JQuery-unobtrusive-ajax.
If the chat is not open there aren't any problems.
We would be happy if someone can help us.

Step to reproduce:

1. Replace the placeholders in the sample (--SUBDOMAIN-- --FIRSTKEY-- --DEPLOYMENT_ID-- --BUTTON_ID--) with your test credentials
2. Load the page in server
3. Test that events(begin, fail, complete) work when you click 'Login' button and seeing alert messages
4. Open the chat in bottom right
5. Click 'Login' button again and wont see the alert messages (the ajax events are broken by SalesForce)

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>

<head>
    
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.0.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-ajax-unobtrusive/3.2.6/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"  type="text/javascript"></script>

</head>

<body>

    <form action="https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:signInWithCustomToken?key=vvv" autocomplete="off" data-ajax="true" data-ajax-begin="alert('on begin')"
          data-ajax-complete="alert('on complete')" data-ajax-failure="alert('on fail')" data-ajax-method="POST"
          data-ajax-success="alert('on success')" data-customaction="" id="loginInLineForm" method="post"
          novalidate="novalidate">

        <button type="submit" data-bs-target="#loginPopup" id="submitLoginInLine" name="submitLoginInLine"><i></i><span>Login</span></button>
        
    </form>

    <style type="text/css">
        .embeddedServiceHelpButton .helpButton .uiButton {
            background-color: #005290;
            font-family: "Arial", sans-serif;
        }

        .embeddedServiceHelpButton .helpButton .uiButton:focus {
            outline: 1px solid #005290;
        }
    </style>

    <script src="https://service.force.com/embeddedservice/5.0/esw.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var initESW = function (gslbBaseURL) {
            embedded_svc.settings.displayHelpButton = true; 
            embedded_svc.settings.prepopulatedPrechatFields = {}
            embedded_svc.settings.brand = 'Hello World';
            embedded_svc.settings.language = 'EN';
            embedded_svc.settings.translationMap = new Map([
                ['EN', 'Sorry, we are not online at the moment. Please leave a message and we will get back to you shortly.']
            ]); 

            embedded_svc.settings.extraPrechatFormDetails = [{
                "label": "Language",
                "value": "EN", 
                "transcriptFields": ["Language__c"],
                "displayToAgent": true
            }, {
                "label": "Brand",
                "value": "Hello World", 
                "transcriptFields": ["Brand__c"],
                "displayToAgent": true
            }];


            embedded_svc.settings.enabledFeatures = ['LiveAgent'];
            embedded_svc.settings.entryFeature = 'LiveAgent';

            embedded_svc.init(
                'https://--SUBDOMAIN--.my.salesforce.com',
                'https://--SUBDOMAIN--.my.salesforce-sites.com/liveAgentSetupFlow',
                gslbBaseURL,
                '--FIRSTKEY--',
                'Chat_Queue',
                {
                    baseLiveAgentContentURL: 'https://c.la1-c2-lo3.salesforceliveagent.com/content',
                    deploymentId: '--DEPLOYMENT_ID--',
                    buttonId: '--BUTTON_ID--',
                    baseLiveAgentURL: 'https://d.la1-c2-lo3.salesforceliveagent.com/chat',
                    eswLiveAgentDevName: 'Chat_Queue',
                    isOfflineSupportEnabled: true
                }
            );
        };

        if (!window.embedded_svc) {
            var s = document.createElement('script');
            s.setAttribute('src', 'https://--SUBDOMAIN--.my.salesforce.com/embeddedservice/5.0/esw.min.js');
            s.onload = function () {
                initESW(null);
            };
            document.body.appendChild(s);
        } else {
            initESW('https://service.force.com');
        }

    </script>
    
</body>

</html>
```